# convert sql to linq with two tables

Tags: c#, .net, linq, join, lambda

```
select ind.desc,ind.number
from int_goals_df idd, goals_df ind
where idd.dld_number = 123456
and ind.number = idd.ind_number
and ind.categorie = 2
order by follownumber
```

I'm having a hard time translating this to linq since it is using two tables.
I've currently solved this now imperatively with a foreach loop but not happy with it..

I'm trying to get a list of `goals_df` that matches with a list of `int_goals_df`.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated ! Thank you !

**EDIT** - here is the code I'm using:

```
//get current GoalDefinitions by selected Goal
var currentGoalDefinition = MyAppAppContext.MyAppAppContextInstance.MyAppContext.GoalDefinitions.FirstOrDefault(
    d => d.DLD_GoalDFID == interv.Goal.DLD_GoalenDFID);

// get current intervGoalDefinitions by GoalDefinition
var currentintervGoalDefinitions = MyAppAppContext.MyAppAppContextInstance.MyAppContext.intervGoalDefinitions.Where(
    idd => idd.DLD_GoalDFID == currentGoalDefinition.DLD_GoalDFID).OrderBy(idd => idd.IDD_VolgNummer);

intervDefinitionCollection = new ObservableCollection<intervDefinition>(MyAppAppContext.MyAppAppContextInstance.MyAppContext.intervDefinitions.Where(i => i.IND_Categorie == intCategorie));

// filter intervGoalDefinitions by intervDefinitions
var intervDefinitionCollectionTemp = new ObservableCollection<intervDefinition>();
foreach (var currentintervGoalDefinity in currentintervGoalDefinitions)
{

    var foundintervGoalDefinitySorted = intervDefinitionCollection.FirstOrDefault(
        i => i.IND_intervDFID == currentintervGoalDefinity.IND_intervDFID);

    if (foundintervGoalDefinitySorted != null)
    intervDefinitionCollectionTemp.Add(foundintervGoalDefinitySorted);
}

intervDefinitionCollection = intervDefinitionCollectionTemp;
```

Comment: So what IS your current solution with that you are not happy? Show some code please

Comment: Need to know your detail regarding your objects. What do you have representing this record?

Answer (score 1):

assuming NHibernate as ORM and int_goal is a subclass of goal

```cs
var results = from idd in session.Query<IntGoals>()
              where idd.DlDNumber = 123456 && idd.Category.Id == 2
              orderby idd.FollowNumber
              select new { idd.Description, idd.Number };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
context.int_goals_df.Join(context.goals_df, x => x.ind_number, x => x.number,
    (x, y) => new
    {
        idd = x,
        ind = y
    })
    .Where(x => x.idd.dld_number = 123456 && x.ind.categorie = 2)
    .OrderBy(x => x.idd.follownumber)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        x.ind.desc,
        x.ind.number
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

quick go  - think you need the join

```
var results = from idd in session.Query<int_goals_df>()
          join ind in session.Query<goals_df>()
          on   idd.ind_number equals ind.ind_number
          where idd.DlDNumber = 123456 && idd.Category.Id == 2
          orderby idd.FollowNumber
          select new { idd.Description, idd.Number };
```

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use the sql syntax without implicit joins

```
/*Fields*/
    SELECT ind.desc, ind.number
/*Tables*/
    FROM int_goals_df idd
    INNER JOIN goals_df ind
    ON ind.number = idd.ind_number
/*Conditions*/
    WHERE idd.dld_number = 123456
    AND ind.categorie = 2
/*Order/Grouping*/
    ORDER BY follownumber
```

You can see from Chris's answer this translates more easily to linq.